# How to use "|" to concatenate multiple numpy.flatiter object

Tags: python, numpy

Any one know why I cannot use "|" to concatenate multiple numpy.flatiter object after converting it inot set? I try to look for all display number 
from all row 11, all column 1 and section from (2,2) to (3,3) if I use np.concatenate I can get the right answer but after I use "|" I have empty set? or if there is a better way to write it?

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.matrix(np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6))
rnum =  matrix[1, :].flat
cnum =  matrix[:, 1].flat
snum = matrix[2:4, 2:4].flat
print(matrix)
print(rnum)
print(set(rnum))
print(set(cnum))
print(set(snum))
print(set(np.concatenate((rnum, cnum, snum))))
print(set(rnum) | set(cnum) | set(snum))
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
# [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15 16 17]
# [18 19 20 21 22 23]
# [24 25 26 27 28 29]
# [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
#<numpy.flatiter object at 0x7faf52966c00>
#{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
#{1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31}
#{20, 21, 14, 15}
#{1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 31} => expect result
#set() => why?
```

Comment: If you must start with `np.matrix` consider using `matrix[...].A1` instead of `.flat` if you want a 1d array.

Comment: any reason for using .A1 is better than .flat?

Comment: `,A1` is an array, so you won't have this 'used-up iterator' problem.  In time tests on your `matrix` `set(matrix.A1)` is a little slower.

Answer (score 3):

The first call of `set(rnum)` in `print(set(rnum))` consumes the iterator `rnum`.  When you use `set(rnum)` again in `set(rnum) | set(cnum) | set(snum)`, there are no more values left in the iterator `rnum`, so `set(rnum)` is the empty set.

Here's a more direct demonstration:

```
In [621]: matrix = np.matrix(np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6))

In [622]: rnum =  matrix[1, :].flat

In [623]: set(rnum)
Out[623]: {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

In [624]: set(rnum)
Out[624]: set()
```

Instead of using `rnum`, you could create another iterator by repeating `matrix[1, :].flat`:

```
In [625]: set(matrix[1, :].flat)
Out[625]: {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

Alternatively, skip the use of `numpy.matrix` and iterators, and just index into a regular NumPy array:

```
In [639]: a = np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6)

In [640]: set(a[1,:])
Out[640]: {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

In [641]: set(a[:,1])
Out[641]: {1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31}

In [642]: set(a[2:4, 2:4].ravel())
Out[642]: {20, 21, 14, 15}
```